# Most Secure Way to Monitoring Raspberry pi data on mobile

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, android-app

I'm Looking for a secure and complete monitoring app available on both Raspberry pi ( apt,...) and Android. I want to monitor some sensitive data and access (like terminal from mobile, the temperature of it, gpio usage, and ram usage, CPU usage, power supply voltage and things like that, as some of the "RaspiController" features) of raspberry pi when I'm working with it on my mobile phone.

I couldn't rely on any of the available apps like RaspiController (for Android), and in the other side, it takes much time to write an Os-compatible and up-to-date app on both Android and Raspberry Pi OS or even run a web server on Raspberry pi ( because of security concerns). So what are your suggestions and what's the best way I have to choose from your idea? (detailed please.)